# How to keep a label widget (Page title) in Tkinter at the top of a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter frame with a title (Questionnaire) in the frame itself, and a bunch of questions I've pulled from a database.

all the questions have been added to a dictionary so they can be associated with a variable, meaning i can create label widgets for the questions using a for loop.

The question labels display fine, and the title displays fine. The problem is that the questions come before the title "Questionnaire" which should be at the top.

```
def QuestionnaireTitle(self):

    Title = Label(self, text='Questionnaire', bg='firebrick', fg='white', width=50, font=('MS', 24, 'bold'))
    Title.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=4, rowspan=1)

def QuestionnaireQuestions(self):


    db = connect("openDay.db")

    allQuestions = []
    questionsDict = dict()

    #Questions

    for i in range(13):
        j = get_questionniare_question(db,i)[0]
        allQuestions.append(j)
        for a in range(len(allQuestions)):
            questionsDict["Q"+str(i)] = allQuestions[i]

    for key,value in questionsDict.items():
        i+=1
        key = Label( text=value, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
        key.grid(row=i, sticky=W)
```

I know when you pull text from a text file or CSV you can use something like this to prevent this sort of thing happening

```
    lines = csv_file.readlines()
    the_title = lines[0]

    the_rest = lines[1:]
```

Is there a similar method for working with databases? or is it exactly the same? would I have to put the "Questionnaire" in the database itself to work with it like that? or can it stay in the python script itself as a label?

Appologies if the question isn't all that clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to place the "QuestionnaireTitle" under the *main* call. Do not make it a function call but just place the lines after you define root. Since you do not have that part of your code shown, here is how I've done it in mine:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

   root = Tkinter.Tk()
   root.minsize(width=250, height=50)

   Title = Label(self, text='Questionnaire', bg='firebrick', fg='white', width=50, font=('MS', 24, 'bold'))
   Title.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=4, rowspan=1)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked. Can you mark this as the correct answer (the green check mark next to it) so others know and it will help my reputation ;)